# How to Populate asp:Textbox using value in ComboBox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, combobox

I have this combobox and I need to populate a textbox with the selected combobox value on the clientside.  What I have doesn't seem to be working.  Am I doing this correctly?

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="cmbOutputRating" runat="server" 
DropDownStyle="DropDown" 
AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" 
CaseSensitive="false" 
RenderMode="Inline" 
ItemInsertLocation="Append"
onchange="javascript:ddlChange();">
</asp:ComboBox>
```

Here is the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOutputRating" runat="server" 
CssClass="inputFieldSmall" 
OnTextChanged="txtOutputRating_TextChanged"
AutoPostBack="True" 
meta:resourcekey="txtOutputRatingResource1">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function ddlChange() 
{
    var cmb = document.getElementById('<%=cmbOutputRating.ClientID %>');
    var textBox = document.getElementById('<%= txtOutputRating.ClientID%>');
    textBox.value = cmb.options[cmb.selectedIndex].value;
}
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Why does **txtOutputRating** has **OnTextChanged** event and postback to server? If you know that **cmbOutputRating** selection is changed, **cmbOutputRating** could just postback to server by itself instead of triggering to **txtOutputRating**. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Win, txtOutputRating will be hidden from the user and is doing quite a few calculations on the backend.  I need whatever value the user types into/selects from cmbOutputRating and update txtOutputRating with it. Once that happens, the rest of the work is done with txtOutputRating.  This is just lazy means of not having to change everything txtOutputRating touches.

Comment: Why not have a `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event for the combobox and do some c# code in the code behind file to set the value of the textbox to `cmbOutputRating.SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: @AzNjoE I need it to happen on the front end instantly without having to do a postback.

Comment: I don't know about that but if you wrap the combobox and the textbox in an updatepanel and do a "postback", it will only refresh the panel and its objects rather than the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

The combobox is rendered as an input so you would grab the value of it like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ddlChange() 
{
var cmb = document.getElementById('<%=cmbOutputRating.ClientID %>');
var textBox = document.getElementById('<%= txtOutputRating.ClientID%>');
textBox.value = cmb.value;
}
</script>
```